# ActionCable.server.broadcast from the console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I can use the following code in the controller but not in the console (both development environment). I'm using Rails 5.0.0.beta2.

```
ActionCable.server.broadcast 'example_channel', message: '<p>Test</p>'
```

The console:

```
>> ActionCable.server.broadcast 'example_channel', message: '<p>Test</p>'
[ActionCable] Broadcasting to example_channel: {:message=>"<p>Test</p>"}
=> []
```

How can I use it in the console?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

The default behavior for ActionCable in development mode is to use the `async` adapter, which operates within the same process only. For inter-process broadcasting, you will need to switch to the `redis` adapter.

To enable redis in development mode, you will need to edit `config/cable.yml`:

```
redis: &redis
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1

production: *redis
development: *redis
test: *redis
```

Comment: im having `Redis::CannotConnectError: Error connecting to Redis on localhost:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)` on my Mac. :(

Comment: @YakobUbaidi do you have the latest version of Redis installed and running at the same time as your rails server?

Comment: Try `brew install redis`, then: `redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis.conf`

Comment: i still get this error
NoMethodError: undefined method `fetch' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Thanks for this answer! You should also make sure including gem 'redis' on your Gemfile.

Comment: Great, thank you! this was the fix of the issue i was having, basically i wasnt able to broadcast from my workers and syncing my views