# ActionCable Not Receiving Data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I created the following using ActionCable but not able to receive any data that is being broadcasted.

**Comments Channel**:

```
class CommentsChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    stream_for comment
  end
end
```

**JavaScript**:

```
var cable = Cable.createConsumer('ws://localhost:3000/cable');

var subscription = cable.subscriptions.create({
  channel: "CommentsChannel",
  id: 1
},{
  received: function(data) {
    console.log("Received data")
  }
});
```

It connects fine and I can see the following in the logs:

```
CommentsChannel is streaming from comments:Z2lkOi8vdHJhZGUtc2hvdy9FdmVudC8x
```

I then broadcast to that stream:

```
ActionCable.server.broadcast "comments:Z2lkOi8vdHJhZGUtc2hvdy9FdmVudC8x", { test: '123' }
```

The issue is that the `received` function is never called. Am I doing something wrong?

Note: I'm using the `actioncable` npm package to connect from a BackboneJS application.

Comment: Changing the cable adapter from `async` to `redis` in `config/cable.yml` fixed it.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Changing the cable adapter from `async` to `redis` in `config/cable.yml` fixed it for me.

**Update**

As Erem pointed out below, the server and console are isolated processes so you need to use a centralized queue manager.

Comment: Awesome, had the same problem. Glad you posted the solution! Worked for me.

Comment: @Artem It didn't work for me. Broadcasting is not working even if redis is used. The server console says: "[ActionCable] Broadcasting to room_channel: {:message=>"llllllllllll"}". But the received function is not called. I tried with both asyn adapter and redis adapter.

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work for you but make sure the redis server is running and the redis host is set in `cable.yml`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35176934/actioncable-server-broadcast-from-the-console

Comment: @sufinsha were you able to figure it out? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: @sufinsha was it a typo? In my js I am connecting like `App.cable.subscriptions.create("NotificationsChannel", { ... }` and in my ruby I got `class NotificationsChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel`, that should be correct right?

Comment: I assume your broadcasting from your rails console? The server and the console are using isolated processes. You need to have a centralized queue manager. You need to use redis.

Comment: Solved for me as well. So strange. Thanks @ArtemKalinchuk

Comment: @Erem does that mean broadcasting from the console(like when testing a new channel) and the actual broadcast from the app's workflow require different adapters? Redis when in console, async when not? Sorry for this newbie inquiry.

Comment: testing from browser, instead of console fixed it for me