# Rails ActionCable stops working after some time in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, puma, actioncable

I am having issues with action cable websocket connections, in development. When I start puma it works fine (connection is open, I can send data back and forth), and then after few page reloads, it just stop working.. No error is thrown.

```
Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-12 11:49:21 +0200
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
Started GET "/cable" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-12 11:49:22 +0200
Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-12 11:49:22 +0200
Started GET "/user/projects/11/forecast" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-12 11:49:22 +0200
Started GET "/notifications?limit=30" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-12 11:49:22 +0200
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
```

In browser I see switching protocols 101, and that's it.

I am using Rails 5.0.3, Ruby 2.2.2p95, Puma server 3.9.1, ActionCable is also 5.0.3.

cable.yml is a standard one:

```
development:
  adapter: async
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure if this will help but check this related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36266746/actioncable-not-receiving-data)

Comment: @BrandonElder as I remember, according to documentation, Async adapter do not assure that messages will be delivered. However, I am having issue that connection is broken.

Comment: After some investigations, it turns out that problem arises because of browserify - actioncable/ws breaks after i change my js code and browserify compiles js... I posted an issue on browserify-rails.