# Getting Action Cable to broadcast in Sidekiq Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, actioncable

I'm using Rails 5 in a docker environment and I can get Action Cable to broadcast on a Sidekiq worker perfectly fine, using worker.new.perform.

But for the life of me, I cannot get it to broadcast while using worker.perform_async.

Here is my cable.yml:

```
default: &default
 adapter: redis
 url: <%= ENV['REDIS_PROVIDER'] %>

development:
 <<: *default

test:
  <<: *default

production:
  <<: *default
```

Here is my worker:

```
class AdminWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform
    ActionCable.server.broadcast 'admin_channel', content: 'hello'
  end
 end
```

My Admin Channel:

```
class AdminChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
 def subscribed
  stream_from "admin_channel"
 end

 def unsubscribed
  # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
 end
end
```

As I mentioned earlier, this works just fine when calling AdminWorker.new.perform.  As soon as I try to run AdminWorker.perform_async, the cable will not broadcast and nothing helpful regarding action cable in the logs.  What am I missing here?

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Did you found any solution?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I had the same problem.  Came across this answer: [ActionCable.server.broadcast from the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35176934/actioncable-server-broadcast-from-the-console) - worked for me.  Basically just changed cable.yml

```
development:
  adapter: async
```

to

```
development:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1
```

and I was able to broadcast from console, models, Sidekiq worker classes, etc.

Comment: Thanks, this was precisely my issue wasnt able to make my workers broadcasting and syncing my views and this solved the issue, specially the link provided

Answer (score 1):

For those who wants to dockerize rails and sidekiq, you should run action_cable server separately like

`puma -p 28080 cable/config.ru`

https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/dockerize-a-rails-5-postgres-redis-sidekiq-action-cable-app-with-docker-compose

https://github.com/kchrismucheke/dockersample/blob/da5923899fb17682fabed041bef5381ed3fd91ab/config/application.rb#L57-L62

Comment: My actioncable server is running separately. Can you still broadcast from console?

Answer (score 0):

**In development environment**
By default, ActionCable would run only on the rails server only. And it would not work in Sidekiq, console, cron jobs, etc.
**Because**  in **config/cable.yml** development server adapter is set to async

**Solution:**
For ActionCable inter-process broadcasting, you have to set the adapter to Redis

In **config/cable.yml**

```
development:
 adapter: redis
 url: redis://localhost:6379/1
 channel_prefix: project_name_development
```