# Actioncable broadcast not working from console in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I used actioncable on rails 5 app. Below code work in controller but not in console.

```
ActionCable.server.broadcast "connector_app", content: "test message"
```

Response:

```
[ActionCable] Broadcasting to connector_app: {:content=>"test message"}
=> nil
```

cable.yml

```
development:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1

test:
  adapter: async

production:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1
```

Contoller code( It works properly):

```
def sample_socket_message
    ActionCable.server.broadcast "connector_app",
      content:  "test message",
    head :ok
end
```

Problem Solved:
Forget to add below code in config/initializer/redis.rb

```
$redis = Redis.new(:host => 'localhost', :port => 6379)
```

Comment: I still have the same issue, even with the right redis config, any other suggestions?

Comment: what are the error messages you can in terminal?

Comment: I fixed the issue too. I was pointing my cable to a different DB id in redis other than the one in the `config/initializers/redis.rb` of the application

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ActionCable.server.broadcast from the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35176934/actioncable-server-broadcast-from-the-console)

Answer (score 31):

The default behavior for ActionCable in development and test mode is to use the async adapter, which operates within the same process only. For inter-process broadcasting, you will need to switch to the redis adapter.

Since you are using redis adapter in development that's why it is working in controller and not working in console.

cable.yml

```
test:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. BTW, I do think SO should allow highest voted answer to be automatically accepted if a certain length of period (say 3 months) elapsed.