# ActionCable.server.broadcast from console always returns 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to get actioncable working, but when I send out ActionCable.server.broadcast "discussion", {asdf: true} in rails console it always returns 0.

I have the redis server running and configured in cable.yml.

Any advice as to what I'm doing wrong would be apperciated.

Rails

```
DiscussionChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
DiscussionChannel is streaming from discussion_channel
```

Rails Console

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 17262
Loading development environment (Rails 5.2.2)
2.6.0 :001 > ActionCable.server.broadcast "discussion", {asdf: true}
[ActionCable] Broadcasting to discussion: {:asdf=>true}
 => 0
```

discussion_channel.rb

```
class DiscussionChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
     stream_from "discussion_channel"
  end

  def unsubscribed
  end

end
```

discussion.coffee

```
App.discussion = App.cable.subscriptions.create "DiscussionChannel",
  connected: ->

  disconnected: ->

  received: (data) ->
     console.log(data)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ActionCable.server.broadcast from the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35176934/actioncable-server-broadcast-from-the-console)

Answer (score 0):

This question is a possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35176934/actioncable-server-broadcast-from-the-console) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42554323/actioncable-broadcast-not-working-from-console-in-rails).

Basically the default behaviour for ActionCable in development mode is to use the `async` adapter, which operates within the same process only.
Since your rails console and rails server run in different processes, calling `ActionCable::Server#broadcast` in the console will not work by default. For inter-process broadcasting, you will need to change the configuration in `config/cable.yml` to use Redis in development as well.